# How to make SQL delete method validate the data properly

Tags: java, sql, database, methods

I got a method that deletes a record in the database when inserting a tag value. when a record is deleted, a message in the console screen pops up saying "this record has been deleted ". It works fine when inserting a valid tag value. However, when I insert an invalid tag value that doesn't exist in my database it acts like it has deleted it and displays that previous message. Although within my method says if the outcome is not equal 1 (which is not true) return false, but it's apparently not validating the inserted data. Can anyone tell me what's the problem

```
public boolean DeleteWallet(String Tag) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("Deleting wallet");
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    int result = 0;
    String query = "DELETE FROM wallets WHERE Tag = '" + Tag + "';";
    try {
        dbConnection = getDBConnection();
        statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("The record has been deleted successfully");
        // execute SQL query
        result = statement.executeUpdate(query);
    } finally {
        if (statement != null) {
            statement.close();
        }
        if (dbConnection != null) {
            dbConnection.close();
        }
    }
    if (result == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How many rows are there for each tag?

Comment: Please learn how to properly use a PreparedStatement. https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-delete-a-record/

Answer (score 0):

The statement
`System.out.println("The record has been deleted successfully");`

is being printed before you actually perform any database operations `statement.executeUpdate(query);`

Instead, you should perform your database operation within your try statement, then print your success output.  If the statement fails (IE an exception is thrown) the success statement will be skipped.

Additionally, instead of relying on the output the the `executeUpdate(query)` to determine if your query was successful, I would always assume your query or some operation before the query fails, and only return true if all database processing was successful.

Finally, the use of prepared statements will help make your query easier to read, use, and is better secured against SQLInjection attacks.

Example:

```java
public class DatabaseOperations {
    public boolean DeleteWallet(String Tag) {
        //Query used for prepared statement
        static final String DELETE_QUERY = "DELETE FROM wallets WHERE Tag=?"; 
        System.out.println("Attempting to delete wallet using query:" + DELETE_QUERY);
        //assume DELETE operation fails due to exection at any stage
        Boolean result = false; 

        try (
            //Objects that can automatically be closed at the end of the TRY block
            //This is known as AutoCloseable
            Connection dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            PreparedStatement statment = dbConnection.preparedStatement(DELETE_QUERY)) 
        {
            //replace ? with Tag
            statement.setString(1, Tag);
            int row = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            //If statement fails skip to catch block

            result = true;
            System.out.println("The record in row " + row + " has been deleted successfully");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            //likely thrown due to "Record Not Found"
            //TODO investigate further for the specific exception thrown from the database implementation you are using.
            //TODO print helpful message to help user of this method resolve this issue
        } catch (Exception) {
            //TODO handle any other exceptions that may happen
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and I would expect there to be a more-specific exception class (a descendant of *SQLException* ...) which would allow you to know exactly what the problem was.

Comment: Thank you for these clarifications, I applied what you have said but the issue still persists. It is not skipping the success statement when I put an invalid tag for some reason!

Comment: I updated the example code to be more precise, introduced the concept of Prepared Statements, AutoClosable, and added in TODOs for you to complete in regards to exception handling.  If you are still having issues please link to your source code if you can and let us know where you are calling this method from.